# How to hide Angular typescript current div and show another div

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm tried to hide Angular typescript  current div and show another div but its not working correctly dose anyone know some solution?

here the code

**html**

```
<div class="m-t-10">
  <div >

    <div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 1 </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="showSelected">

    <div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 2 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
showSelected: boolean;    

constructor() {
  this.showSelected = false;
}

ToggleButton() {
  this.showSelected = !this.showSelected;
}
```

Comment: Your component 1 div should have `*ngIf="!showSelected"`

Comment: CSS display:none for one of the classes and display: block for the other then JS to toggle two classes DOMElement.classlist.toggle(1stclass, 2ndclass)? Could that work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) on both component wrappers, or ngIf with [ngTemplate](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template). When you have more than 2 possible components you can use a [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

1. `ngIf` example

```html
  <div *ngIf="!showSelected">
    <div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 1 </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="showSelected">
    <div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 2 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

2. `ngIf` with `ngTemplate` example

```html
  <div>
    <div *ngIf="!showSelected; else otherComponent" class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 1 </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <ng-template #otherComponent>
    <div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 2 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

3. `ngSwitchCase` example

```html
  <div [ngSwitch]="selectedComponentName">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'component1'" class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'component2'" class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'component3'" class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
      <p> component 3 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your HTML should be like:**

```
<div *ngIf="!showSelected">
<div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
  <p> component 1 </p>
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="showSelected">
<div class="circle-us"  nzTooltipTitle="United States" nzTooltipPlacement="top"  nz-tooltip (click)="ToggleButton()">
  <p> component 2 </p>
</div>
```